# What does "+" mean in reflected FullName and '*' after Member c#

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm currently dealing with reflection in c#. After:

```
Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.0.7\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll").GetTypes()
```

And i found this:  `[System.Numerics.Matrix4x4], [System.Numerics.Matrix4x4+CanonicalBasis], [System.Numerics.Matrix4x4+VectorBasis]`
(There are reflected types from "System.Numerics.Vectors.dll")
I know that Matrix4x4 is structture, however I can't find any info about CanonicalBasis and VectorBasis, and what "+" means in this context.
I was doing further research and another strange thing is that:

```
Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.0.7\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll").GetType("System.Numerics.Matrix4x4+VectorBasis").FullName
"System.Numerics.Matrix4x4+VectorBasis"
```

But:

```
Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.0.7\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll").GetType("System.Numerics.Matrix4x4+VectorBasis").Name
"VectorBasis"
```

Moreover, when I looked through members of Matrix4x4+VectorBasis there is member like this:

```
[System.Numerics.Vector3* Element0]
```

And is it raw pointer like in c++? Or what is it?

P.S. I was doing it in c# interactive, but i don't think it had any influence on results.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `+` between class names means that the part after the `+` is a nested type of the type which name is before the `+`. For example `Dictionary<string, string>+KeyCollection`. `KeyCollection` is an  inner class of `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`.

The `*` denotes a pointer indeed, since [the field mentioned](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Numerics/System/Numerics/Matrix4x4.cs,1478) is in unsafe mode:

```
public unsafe Vector3* Element0;
```

Comment: However if I do: 
Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.0.7\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll").GetType("System.Numerics.Matrix4x4").GetNestedTypes() 
I get:
Type[0] { }

Comment: @Kacper `GetNestedTypes` only shows you **public** nested types. See my answer

Comment: @Kacper use `GetNestedTypes(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)` to get *all* the nested types.

Comment: Is this naming pattern (`+` for nested types) actually defined in the spec, or is it just the current compiler version's convention?

Answer (score 4):

In the string `System.Numerics.Matrix4x4+VectorBasis`, `+` means that `VectorBasis` is a nested type of `Matrix4x4`. In this particular case `VectorBasis` is a nested `struct` inside of a `class`. Note that `+` is the same symbol not matter what kind of nested type you're dealing with:

```
class A
{
    public class B {}
}

struct A
{
    public struct B {}
}

class A
{
    public enum B {}  
}
```

All nested types in these examples have the same `FullName`, `A+B`.

In your case, `VectorBasis` and `CanonicalBasis` are `private` members, that's why you can't see them through `Type.GetNestedTypes()` which only shows `public` members.

---

The `*` after `System.Numerics.Vector3*` means that it is a [pointer type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/pointer-types). The string comes from the `Type` instance of the `FieldInfo.FieldType` property.

---

You can look up this and other possible string representations of the `Type` class on  the corresponding page of the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname(v=vs.110).aspx).